# Import CSV foreach loop process

Tags: iis, powershell, foreach

I am working on an issue and I can't seem to get the syntax correct.

I have a directory which has a series of csv files which each contain a list of virtual directories and paths from an old IIS6 machine.  I am recreating those on a new IIS7.5 machine and I am able to get them added one directory at a time by going to the directory "iis:\sites\Atlanta" and running this command.

```
Import-Csv C:\Users\MIGXHZ700\Desktop\Atlanta.csv | Where-Object {$_.Path -match "\\"} | ForEach-Object {New-Item $_.Name -Type VirtualDirectory -physicalPath $_.Path}
```

For the life of me I can't get the syntax right to run this in a script.  I think it's just an issue with concatenation, but I am not 100% sure.  Here is where I am at with the script.

```
$dirs = ls C:\Users\[blah]\Desktop\*.csv | foreach-object {
    Import-Csv $_ | 
    Where-Object {$_.Path -match "\\"} |
    ForEach-Object {New-Item 'IIS:\Sites\'+$_.Name -Type VirtualDirectory -physicalPath $_.Path}
}
```

It also might be an issue doing Foreach inside of a Foreach?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you post a copy of one of the CSV files - just the first five or six lines will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'IIS:\Sites\'+$_.Name` is not a valid argument to **New-Item**, because the **-Path** parameter takes a string argument, but that's an expression. It's an expression that *evaluates* to a string representing the path of the item you want to create, but you need to evaluate it by enclosing it in parentheses:

```
New-Item ('IIS:\Sites\' + $_.Name) -Type VirtualDirectory -PhysicalPath $_.Path
```

BTW, what's your intention for **$dirs**? It will be assigned the output of the **New-Item** command, which will be an array of DirectoryInfo objects (the same as what you'd get from `$dirs = Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites\` after creating all those directories). Is that what you want?

Comment: Yeah I will be using $dirs to do something beyond the scope of this snippet.